# ArduinoArduino keypad matrix w/ SPDT

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm trying to create a keypad matrix with an Arduino. I want do a 5x5 grid but I've run into a problem. I'm using standard momentary SPST push buttons and 2 position SPDT toggle switches (On/Off) setup to switch columns in a row. The switches are the issue. Attached is a partial of my grid layout showing how the SPDT switches short the columns. Is there a way to fix this?

[image: Grid Layout]

Comment: although you'll probably get an answer here, you should also consider migrating/posting the question in Electronics StackExchange and ArduinoSE.

Comment: You state switches are an issue. I am assuming toggle switches are the issue. If so can you please edit the question to improve clarity. Also can you please describe the issue. Also as you may realize the toggle switches are either ON or OFF. So you will have t address this in your code. I would suggest sharing the key scan code as part of the question. Lastly what yo have is a 5x2 keypad, not a 5 x5 so some the positions are don't care.

Comment: Why do this in hardware?  You are attempting to combine a polled pushbotton array with fixed switches.  I'm assuming button presses cause the Arduino to do something.  Easier to do it in software.  And it would of gotten a quicker response on Electronics or Arduino.

Comment: The issue is that since the toggle switches are NC they short columns together.

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.electroons.com/8051/electroons/matrix_keypad.html this might help you.

Comment: It is quite clear what the issue is.  Push buttons are meant to connect Row to Column, so if you put a pattern out on Row, detecting it on Column, means pushbutton at intersection was pressed.  Not meant for SPDT switches.  Do it in software!

Comment: @TomDoolan, Any reason that you place to toggle switches in the Matrix. What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve. May there is a simpler solution.